# Getting 'Repository does not exist' when pushing from cloud9 toBitbucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the book Ruby on Rails Tutorial Micheal Hartl recommends using the Cloud9 https://c9.io cloud IDE.  I created a Bitbucket account, set up Git on the IDE, and installed Rails on Cloud9.

```
git push -u origin --all and getting error message conq: Repository does not exist.
fatal: could not read from remote repository
please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exist.
```

Comment: It is likely the line before in the tutorial was not execute correctly:  `git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:<username>/hello_app.git`.  As @Tito mentions, you can log onto your bitbucket account and create the repository there (or at least check whether or not it was created).

Comment: Thanks.  I see that the repo was created on bitbucket.  The problem is when I try and push the rails hello.app project to bit bucket.   using git push -u origin --all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log into the Bitbucket website and navigate to the dashboard.  On the overview tab, you should see a link like 'john_larkin / hello_app'.  Click on the link and you will see the Overview page for this repository.  At the top right of the page, you will see an SSH select.  The name of your repository appears to the right of that select.  It should look something like:

```
git@bitbucket.org:john_larkin/hello-app.git
```

In your Cloud9 terminal session for the hello app project, issue the command:

```
git remote add origin <repo>
```

replacing `<repo>` with your repository name from Bitbucket.

Once you do this, you should be able to successfully push your code and updates to your repository.

**SSH Key**

If you are still experiencing issues, make sure you have successfully loaded your SSH key from your Cloud9 IDE into Bitbucket:

1. Go to https://bitbucket.org/.
2. Click on your avatar in the upper right hand corner of the page and select 'Manage account'.
3. Click on the 'SSH Keys' link under Security on the left side panel.
4. You should see a key listed there - click on the 'edit' link (if you don't see a key, click on the 'Add key' button to add a new key).
5. On your Cloud9 IDE, click on your avatar at the top of the screen and select 'Dashboard'.  Click on 'Show SSH key' on the right of the screen to view your Cloud9 SSH key.  This key should match what appears in the Bitbucket edit view.  If it does not or you are unsure, you can always delete this key and create a new key by copying your Cloud9 key into Bitbucket.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I did that, but I continue with the same error message.

Comment: What do you see in the terminal when you run the `git remote...` command?

Comment: fatal: Repository already exists.    sorry it says fatal: remote origin already exists

Comment: Sounds like there may be a problem with your SSH key. I've updated my answer to include steps to check and/or create your key in Bitbucket.

Comment: yea I deleted those SSH keys and copied them back in to bitbucket.  No luck same error message.  ugh.

Comment: Great to hear John... on to the next problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I got problem to configure C9 and Bitbucket, but after fighting, i win. So, in the first time, for myself i just delete my repo and my app, i was only on the beginning of creation. If its not your case, im not sure, but if you click (upper left) option to show hidden file and delete the .git, that can probably help.

So, i will enumerate my step that make the connection between C9 and Bitbucket working for me.

**In C9**

1. git config --global user.name "Your name"
2. git config --global user.email "email@exemple.com"
3. git init
4. git add -A
5. git commit -m "Creation of my application"
6. cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub *(take all ssh key except email)*

**In Bitbucket**

7. Add SSH key in Bitbucket Settings
8. Create Repository

**In C9 add Bitbucket code exemple**

9. git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:(user info)
10. git remote -v *(to see if its correct)*
11. git push -u origin master

**At this stage, all should be pushed to Bitbucket**

After to push again your code to Bitbucket

- git add -A
- git commit -m "Your comment here"
- git push

Hope that can help some people.

Answer (score 0):

Create a remote repository, in the web site, before pushing it from your local repository.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. Make sure you added something to the repository with

```
git add -A
```

and then

```
git add -m "Your message"
```

Then try to push the repository upstream.